# PHP escape certain $_post value out of loop

Tags: php, foreach, sql-update

I got a form which passes dynamic stock qty send to update in database, as below:

```
if($_POST) {

    $cid = $_POST['prod_id'];

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        $q  = "UPDATE `stock` SET";
        $q .= " in_stock=in_stock + '".$value."'";
        $q .= " WHERE cid='".$cid."' AND sid='".$key."'";

        echo $q.'<br />';
    }

}
```

However, the echo queries is output like:

```
UPDATE `stock` SET in_stock=in_stock + '2' WHERE cid='2' AND sid='prod_id'
UPDATE `stock` SET in_stock=in_stock + '1' WHERE cid='2' AND sid='qty-2'
UPDATE `stock` SET in_stock=in_stock + '2' WHERE cid='2' AND sid='qty-3'
UPDATE `stock` SET in_stock=in_stock + '3' WHERE cid='2' AND sid='qty-4'
UPDATE `stock` SET in_stock=in_stock + '8' WHERE cid='2' AND sid='qty-5'
```

The first query should not be include in a loop, but that is part of $_post input for `cid`, is there any workaround to escape the first query out of the update loop?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: you _send_ an _UPDATE_ statement to a system?

Comment: Oh, you are building query by hand using raw user input. That's sweet..

Comment: @Elon Than, just for easy understanding, it's not raw and direct to db

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As repox mentioned, inserting a simple array_shift() to remove the first element of the array would be easy:

```
if($_POST) {

    $cid = $_POST['prod_id'];
    array_shift($_POST);
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    ...
```

But since you cannot rely on that you recieve the form elements always in the same order (or will not add other elements in the future), i would instead recommend filtering them:

```
    ...
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        if (!preg_match('/^qty-/', $key)) continue;
        $q  = "UPDATE `stock` SET";
        ...
```